# flutter SpeechRecognitionError only on Simulator iPhone SE/14/14pro, but working on real iPhone device

Tags: ios, flutter, speech-to-text

The speech recognition function is working well on real iPhone device, but can't work on the simulator iPhone SE/14/14pro...

- All permissions are allowed on the simulators.
- Package version: speech_to_text: ^6.1.1

```dart
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
...
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechEnabled = await _speech.initialize(
      onStatus: (val) => print(' onStatus: $val'),
      onError: (val) => print(' onError: $val'),
    );
    setState(() {
    });
  }
  void _startListening() async {
    print(" _startListening, current isListen: ${_speech.isListening}");
    await _speech.listen(
      onResult: _onSpeechResult,
      listenFor: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      partialResults: true,
      localeId: 'en_US',);
    setState(() {});
  }
...
```

The console for simulator

[image]

```
flutter:  _startListening, current isListen: false
flutter:  onStatus: notListening
flutter:  onError: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_listen_failed, permanent: true
flutter:  onStatus: done
flutter:  onStatus: notListening
flutter:  onStatus: done
flutter:  onError: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_retry, permanent: true
```

The console for real iPhone 6s device:
[image]

I haven't found a working way for such case, appreciate any help.